# Paypal form with email and paypal

Tags: php, forms, paypal

I am trying to make form that have some fields like name,email,file_upload and some radio button options. What I need :

1) When user submit a form all of his detail send to my email address and he will be redirect to paypal for payment.

my form code :

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" onsubmit="this.target='_blank'; return ReadForm(this, true);" name="myForm" class="payment-form ">

       <div class="left-section">


     <input name="cmd" value="_xclick" type="hidden">
<input name="add" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="business" value="test@gmail.com " type="hidden">
<input name="shipping" value="0.00" type="hidden">
<input name="no_shipping" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="return" value="" type="hidden">
<input value="Select Inner Pages, +85.00, +00.00 no-font-image-replacement, +00.00 no-favicon, +99.00 wordpress integration, +00.00 no-all-in-one-seo" name="item_name" type="hidden">
<input value="184.00" name="amount" type="hidden">
<input name="currency_code" value="USD" type="hidden">
<input name="lc" value="US" type="hidden">
<input name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF" type="hidden">

<div class="d-section"> 

    <label class="delivery">
 <input class="DEPENDS ON basedes "   onclick="ReadForm (this.form, false);" name="pepperoni" onchange="choixPersonne('cacher1')" value="+120.00" type="radio">
      <p>24 Hour fastest  delivery</p>    
      <span>$120 Home page    $30 inner pages</span></label>


    <label class="delivery">
        <input class="DEPENDS ON basedes "   onclick="ReadForm (this.form, false);" name="pepperoni" value="+85.00" type="radio" onchange="choixPersonne('cacher2')" ><p>2,3 Business day delivery</p>  <span> $85 Home page     $30 inner pages</span></label>
    <label class="delivery">
        <input class="DEPENDS ON basedes "  onclick="ReadForm (this.form, false);" name="pepperoni" value="+70.00" type="radio"><p>5,6 Day Calm Delivery</p> <span> $70 Home page     $25 inner pages</span> </label><br>





             </div>
              <h4>How many pages you need</h4>



        <p>
    <select size="1" onclick="ReadForm (this.form, false);" name="basedes" class="pages-count">
        <option selected="selected">Select Inner Pages</option>
        <option value="2 pages">2 pages ----- $60.00</option>
        <option value="2 pages">3 pages ----- $90.00</option>
        <option value="4 pages">4 pages ----- $120.00</option>
        <option value="2 pages">5 pages ----- $150.00</option>
        <option value="6 pages">6 pages ----- $180.00</option>
        <option value="2 pages">7 pages ----- $210.00</option>
        <option value="2 pages">8 pages ----- $240.00</option>
        <option value="2 pages">9 pages ----- $270.00</option>
        <option value="2 pages">10 pages ----- $300.00</option>
        <option value="2 pages">11 pages ----- $320.00</option>
        <option value="2 pages">12 pages ----- $340.00</option>
        <option value="2 pages">13 pages ----- $360.00</option>
        <option value="2 pages">14 pages ----- $380.00</option>
        <option value="2 pages">15 pages ----- $400.00</option>
        <option value="2 pages">16 pages ----- $420.00</option>
        <option value="2 pages">17 pages ----- $440.00</option>
    </select></p>

              <p class="normal-12">Please select amount of inner pages<br>
              <strong>$10 Off</strong> for order of more than 10 pages</p>




              <h4 class="red-order">Your Order Details <p>(Excluding weekends)</p></h4>

              <div class="order-detail-box">

              <div style="height:100px"></div>
              <h5 class="bold-30">TOTAL COST <input class="ack" size="7" name="tot" value="$00.00" type="text"></h5>
                   <div id="rien" style="display:none">baber </div>
```

Nos accords mets et vins fonctionnent uniquement avec les appellations (Exemple : Sauternes, Chinon etc..)

```
              </div>
```

```
           <div class="right-section">
```

```
           <div class="final-form">

           <label>Name</label>
            <input name="name" class="txt-feild" type="text"> 

                           <label>Email</label>
            <input name="email" class="txt-feild" type="text">   


            <label>Upload</label>



          <div id="divinputfile">
<input name="filepc" size="20" id="filepc" onchange="document.getElementById('pc').value = this.value;" type="file">
<div id="inputfile"><input name="pc" id="pc" type="text"></div>
```

```
                                       <label>Project Title</label>
            <input name="project title" class="txt-feild" value="" type="text">


                          <label>Project Note</label>
           <textarea name="area" class="" style="height:109px; width:331px; border:#adaaaa 1px solid;" ></textarea>                    




           </div>
```

```
           </form>
```

Comment: Can you please ask the whole question in English. It'll be helpful for everyone as well as yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just using HTML and JavaScript, or what language are you trying to do this in?  I have set something up like this with PHP.  What I did was just when the end user submitted the form, kicked it over to the PHP script and read the data.  The PHP script sent the email and then did a redirect over to PayPal where it posted need PayPal variables/information.  The buyer then completed the payment and I then redirected the buyer back over to my site once completing the payment on the PayPal site.